# Как организовать регистрацию на сайте через соцсети?

Tags: php, oauth, oauth2, openid

Коллеги, приветствую!

В PHP не новичок, однако с авторизацией через соцсети практически не работал (разве что, в далеком 12-13, но, думаю, с тех пор многое поменялось).

Возникла необходимость реализовать регистрацию через популярные соцсети на сайте, но не используя всякие агрегаторы типа ulogin и пр.

Подскажите хорошую статью для чайников по данной теме - где какие ключи брать, где и как регистрироваться для разработчика, какими библиотеками и как пользоваться?

Comment: "где какие ключи брать" - очевидно, на сайтах интересующих вас соцсетей

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можешь посмотреть вот этот плейлист на Ютубе https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQFEiEF21vY&list=PLB8wmVoWIIx4XL-59V3PXKxKVgy3vfqLB

Там парень рассказывает про авторизацию через Вк, Фейсбук и Яндекс и в ссылках к описанию видео исходники с кодом. Хотя он там все в процедурном стиле пишет, главное там дан пример, можно переписать как угодно.

Для отправки get запросов к API соц. сетей можно использовать стандартную функцию **file_get_contents**, если нужно и get и post, то с помощью **curl**. А так можно погуглить готовую библиотеку, что-то в духе *"php http клиент"*.